# Set up Postgresql-93 on Centos 7

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgresql-9.3

I followed this [Almost idiot's guide](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/329-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.3,-PostGIS-2.1-and-pgRouting-with-Yum.html) to install postgresql and postgis on **Centos 7** and got stuck starting the database itself with the following command:

```
[root@localhost cmaps]# service postgresql-9.3 initdb
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

If I install the postgresql package from Centos repository (version 9.2) the command works, but then I they don't have postgis, and there is no official posgresql-92 repository for Centos 7.

Any idea on what's happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem and solve it by changing the path

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb
```

Note that the path is different

Comment: also, to start the server run: systemctl start postgresql-9.3.service

Comment: It's been 3 years and the wiki still doesn't reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

CentOS 7 is based on systemd. PostgreSQL packages use a different command for initdb there:

```
/usr/lib/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb
```

On older versions, call the initscript directly.

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

Comment: @Gatuno Ah, didn't notice you were on RHEL/CentOS 7. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7.3 installed on **MS Azure platform** the script is located at

```
/usr/bin/postgresql-setup initdb
```

the version number is absent from the name of these as well:

- db data & config location: `/var/lib/pgsql/data/`
- service name `/sbin/service postgresql status` or `systemctl status postgresql.service`